# Are there any tools for highlighting TODOs in a .tex file?

Tags: editors, atom

I am using Atom editor to write a `.tex` file and need tool to annotate it with *TODOs* for my reference. *TODOs* are convenient to run `grep` and get all of the comment lines at once.

Comment: Gedit (for Linux/gnome) highlights TODO comments (in capitals) with a bright yellow background.

Comment: So, are you looking for an alternative editor or a solution for Atom? However, vim highlights `TODO`s. If you prefer a GUI, I'd recommend texstudio which highlights them as well!

Comment: @nox I am actually looking a solution for atom. But, I'll try texstudio and see how it goes.

Comment: do you have the `language-latex` package installed for atom? if you know how, you can adapt it to highlight TODOs

Comment: @naphaneal [this](https://github.com/atom/language-todo/issues/64) is a perfect enhancement from `language-todo` project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In TeXStudio this is quite easy: just write `%todo` or `%TODO` (see screenshot) and the comment will be highlighted. I have tried almost every editor for `LaTeX` and came to the conclusion that TeXStudio is the best one (for me).

[image: A example]

Comment: The list of TODO's also show up in the Structure panel (on the left), which may or may not be useful for OP to know (considering their last sentence in the question).

Answer (score 5):

I addition to Nikola Djordjevic's answer, you can also use the `todo` package, with which you will be able to write todos in your output document, plus print a list of todos in your document at an arbitrary location. Nice gimmick: use the option `disable` to ignore any `todo` commands in the document when you need to pass on your current work to someone else and you don't want them to have to look at the todos, but also don't want to go and comment each one out.

Huge plus for me: TeXStudio will *also* recognize `todo` commands and highlight them and their content, not just the todo comments as shown in Nikola Djordjevic's answer. This way, you can have both, source code comment style todos for just the people with access to the source file *and* command todos included in the document for todos you want to see in the PDF (or on paper). In TeXStudio, both styles will be included in the bookmarks in the left part of the program window.

Additionally, in TeXStudio, you can go to Options > Configure TeXStudio > Adv. Editor and tell TeXStudio which keywords you want it to highlight as todo comments. (Check the checkbox "Show Advanced Options" in the lower left corner of the configuration panel to access the "Adv. Editor" tab.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to switch the editor, TeXStudio is the best choice for editing as pointed by Nikola Djordjevic and thymaro.

For Atom, you can edit the stylesheet to highlight `TODO` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969728/how-to-change-todo-highlight-in-atom-editor) or highlight the entire line as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mrodalgaard/atom-todo-show/issues/173). Other packages for Atom that one might find useful are: `language-latex`, `language-todo` and `todo-show`.

Comment: a replacement package for `language-latex` is `language-latex2e` and can be found here: https://atom.io/packages/language-latex2e